# How to estimate throughput at reception multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, throughput

I have a multithreading messaging application, where nodes exchange multiple packets. I want to estimate the throughput at the reception.
I measure delays between the messages, but I'm not sure if I divide the packet's size by that delay that I can get the correct throughput.

Comment: Hey! Could you provide details about your app, the method you use to measure, code etc.?

Comment: The app is a p2p application with nodes exchanging messages.
I'm using one-way packet delay to measure delays (the difference between departure delays and arrival delays)